# How to convert a PNG to a JPG with PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Okay, people keep saying full code but there's not too much more than I posted.  But here's the full code (which does NOT work although the image input DOES work - I can print out the image type and mode, for example):

```
from PIL import Image
image_file = "E:\Downloads\VolcanicRockDiffuse.png"
test_file = "E:\\temp.jpg"

image = Image.open(image_file)
if image.format == "PNG":
    rgb_im = image.convert('RGB')
    rgb_im.save(test_file)
```

Okay, even this (with the backslash corrected) does not work.  But this DOES work:

...

```
im = Image.open(image_file)
outFile = test_file
buffer = io.BytesIO()
im.save(buffer, format = im.format)
open(outFile, "wb").write(buffer.getvalue())
```

...

So I don't know exactly what to tell you folks.  The Python on my system, at least, will not just work with an Open and then Save to JPG.  The above isn't elegant but it will do for my purposes.

Comment: It might have something to do with the paths. Shouldn't "D://Test.png" be "D:\Test.png"? You should post the full code for the error.

Comment: did you try ```rgb_im.save("jpg_converted_image.jpg")```?

Comment: Please include _all_ the code involved as well as the full error traceback.

Answer (score 1):

you can use pillow to do that.

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("test.png")
rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
rgb_im.save('new_test.jpg')
```

more information related to this follow this link https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert

Comment: Someone was correct above in that the backslash was an issue.  However, even with the backslash corrected it would still not work (IOW, the code to open and then save didn't work even with the paths correct).  I have found code that works but I can't figure out how to put it here - in any case, I had to write the PNG to a buffer, and then save the buffer to the JPG.  That was the only thing that wouldn't crash my system.  If no one has any better solutions I'll post it as my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash is special in strings, e.g. `"\t"` is the tab character, to escape it either double it:

```
test_file = "E:\\Downloads\\temp.jpg"
```

use a raw string:

```
test_file = r"E:\Downloads\temp.jpg"
```

or use forward slashes (they're legal in windows too):

```
    test_file = "E:/Downloads/temp.jpg"
```